# How to configure which characters are allowed in CentOS usernames

Tags: centos, regular-expression, users, login, useradd

In systems such as Debian, there is a file `/etc/adduser.conf` which includes directive NAME_REGEX that can be used to define which characters are allowed in a username.

Is there a way to do this in CentOS 6.9? I can see that there is a file `/etc/default/useradd` but there is no indication anywhere in the documentation that it could support a similar directive.

I would like to be able to create a username with the `@` sign in it, such as `user@domain.com`.

Comment: what are your trying to achieve here ?

Comment: I would like to be able to create a username with the '@' sign in it, such as user@domain.com

Comment: dont do that. it will break so many thing for example you won't be able to connect via ssh on the machine because `ssh user@domain@hostname` will never work.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer. Relevant details should really be added to the question so that it can be answered without having to read the comments.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/879393/131555 interesting question with some background ;-)